# Regex pattern failing when adding an OR?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix

The pattern below works great and I get hundreds of results.

```
xargs pcregrep -M "select.*table(.)*" >> $grep_out
```

This returns (sample):

```
./mo/module1/module1.4gl: call error("Prepare select_table failed.")
./mo/module1/module1.4gl: declare select_table cursor with hold for sel_table
./mo/module1/module1.4gl: let prep = " select * from table ",
```

When I add an OR to the final end character, I get 0 results:

```
xargs pcregrep -M "select.*table(.|\n)*" >> $grep_out
```

This makes absolutely no sense to me. I'm adding an OR - logically, it shouldn't do anything but EXPAND my search, and increase my results. Not decrease them. What's going on here?

Comment: Please add sample data

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with your sample data. Tested with `bash` 4.2.45(1)-release and `pcregrep` 8.31.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using multiline, you'll match the first `select table` in the file, then because of `(.\n)*` you'll match the rest of the file. Note only the single match:

```
$ pcregrep -M "select.*table(.|\n)*" *
file.txt:call error("Prepare select_table failed.")
declare select_table cursor with hold for sel_table
let prep = " select * from table ",
```

There's no problem with the `OR` component, though.

```
$ pcregrep -M "FOO(\n)" *
file.txt:FOO
file.txt:FOO

$ pcregrep -M "FOO(.)" *
file.txt:FOOF

$ pcregrep -M "FOO(.|\n)" *
file.txt:FOO
file.txt:FOOF
file.txt:FOO
```

So, your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Why do you keep putting your asterisk outside of the quotes? And I know it will match the rest of the file - the purpose is to put another string after "(.|\n)", but I've narrowed the problem down to this. Thank you for trying to help test this, but you didn't test the case presented - it's after the SECOND word. Putting "(.|\n)" after the first word works for me, too.

Comment: @user1472747 The asterisk is outside of the quotes because it's testing all files in the current directory; it's a globbing expression, not part of the regex.

Comment: @user1472747 And I did, in fact, test the case presented; that's the first thing in my answer, where `file.txt` contains your to-be-matched lines. Which work when tested with your second regex.